# Django: append URL parameters to a list?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I currently have URLs of the form `/blue` - each URL is a colour. The associated URL pattern is as follows:

```
 (r'^(?P<colour>\w+)$', 'views.colour')
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to have URLs that look like a natural language list, of indeterminate length, separated by `-or-`:

```
/blue-or-green-or-yellow
```

Ideally the associated URL pattern would append each match to a Python list, ready to be handled in the view:

```
 (r'^(?P<colour_list>\w+)(?:-or-(?P<colour_list>\w+))+$', 'views.colour')
```

Is there any way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like `(?P<colour_list>(\w+(\-or\-)?)+)` will get the entire substring match, then you can just split by `-or-`

Note, however, that then `blue-or-` would be valid match, so you may want to split it like this: `filter(bool, colour_list.split('-or-'))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help:

takes comma separated colours

```
(r'^(?P<colours>[\w,]+)$', 'views.colour')
```

then in view:

```
colours = colours.split(',')
```

Comment: I think you were aiming for something more along the lines of `^(?P<colours>[\w,]+)$`, note the position of the `+`

Comment: @DanielB yeah `+` should be there for multiple occurrences, just missed it

Comment: That `+` is still inside the square brackets, meaning `red+blue,green` would be a valid match

Answer (score 0):

Try this `regex`:

```
(\w+(?:-or-)?)+
```

or use string split:

```
result = colours.split("-or-")
```

Comment: That `re.findall` solution will only give the *last* color - try it with `red-or-blue-green` and you'll get `["green"]`